# media element spend's time to load again

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-store-apps, mediaelement, windows-store

I have a BIG problem!when I play a media element in WPF using c# or windows store app using c# with looping enable it takes some time to replay after sound ended an I need to replay it fast to make helicopter's sound.how can I replay a media element faster and without having to wait to load the sound again?tnx.
if(badenglish){sorry();}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont need video perhaps you could use `SoundPlayer` instead as it is a lot faster when looping

Example:

```
var player = new SoundPlayer("myHelicopterSound.wav");
player.PlayLooping();
```

Comment: i will try it in wpf but no idea for windows store apps?I need it there more.thanks

Comment: sorry, I had no idea they removed `SoundPlayer` in `WinRT`, SharpDX could be the only othr way: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/9057c5f7-4228-4102-8427-12ef608ff349/how-to-play-sound-in-c-metro-windows-store-application-with-xaudio-2